# FileWrite BufferedWriter and PrintWriter combined

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter, bufferedwriter

Ok so I am learning about I/O, and I found the following code in one of the slides. can someone please explain why there is a need to have a FileWrite, BufferedWriter and PrintWriter? I know BufferedWriter is to buffer the output and put it all at once but why would they use FileWriter and PrintWriter ? dont they pretty much do the same with a bit of difference in error handling etc?

And also why do they pass `bw` to `PrintWriter`?

```
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (file);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
      PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (bw);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Presumably they're using a `FileWriter` because they want to write to a file. Both `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` have to be given another writer to write to - you need *some* eventual destination.

(Personally I don't like `FileWriter` as it doesn't let you specify the encoding. I prefer to use `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`, but that's a different matter.)

`BufferedWriter` is used for buffering, as you say - although it doesn't buffer *all* the output, just a fixed amount of it (the size of the buffer). It creates "chunkier" writes to the underlying writer.

As for the use of `PrintWriter` - well, that exposes some extra methods such as `println`. Personally I dislike it as it swallows exceptions (you have to check explicitly with `checkError`, which still doesn't give the details and which I don't think I've *ever* seen used), but again it depends on what you're doing. The `PrintWriter` is passed the `BufferedWriter` as *its* destination.

So the code below the section you've shown will presumably write to the `PrintWriter`, which will write to the `BufferedWriter`, which will (when its buffer is full, or it's flushed or closed) write to the `FileWriter`, which will in turn convert the character data into bytes on disk.

Comment: you are saying to pass a BufferedWriter to PrintWriter. Is it really needed? PrintWriter is buffered itself. Try to print something without flushing it.

Comment: @Rollerball: I'm saying that's what the OP *is* doing. Quite possibly the `BufferedWriter` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Rollerball if you don't pass `BufferedWriter` to `PrintWriter` docs states that " ..without buffering, each invocation of a print() method would cause characters to be converted into bytes that would then be written immediately to the file, which can be very inefficient..."

Comment: @Jon thanks for pointing out good alternatives (like FileOutputStream and OutputStreamWriter).   I haven't used PrintWriter in ages but I didn't know about checkError!

Answer (score 8):

From the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

> In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters. For example,

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));
```

> will buffer the PrintWriter's output to the file. Without buffering, each invocation of a print() method would cause characters to be converted into bytes that would then be written immediately to the file, which can be very inefficient.

You can understand from this that a `BufferedWriter` is an efficient way to write stuff.

> Writes text to a character-output stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient writing of single characters, arrays, and strings.

A `FileWriter` object is passed to the `BufferedWriter` as the intent here is to write to some output file using a `BufferedWriter`.

And finally, a `PrintWriter` is used for `print*` methods like `println()`.

Answer (score 3):

PrintWriter from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

> Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream.
>   This class implements all of the print methods found in PrintStream.
>   It does not contain methods for writing raw bytes, for which a program
>   should use unencoded byte streams.

from the above statement it seems the main reason to use PrintWriter is to get the access of all the methods of `PrintStream` like `println()`,`println(char [] x)` etc.

BufferedWriter, You are right It's one of the best way to write to a file because it will buffered the character into the virtual memory before writing to a file directly and came up with a `newLine()` method.

FileWriter from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

> FileWriter is meant for writing streams of characters. For writing
>   streams of raw bytes, consider using a FileOutputStream

.

Answer (score 2):

`FileWriter` is simply to write plain text(without formatting) it doesn't use any buffer mechanism, whatever comes its way it just writes.

`BufferedWriter` is a wrapper for `Writer` classes to allow it to be able to use buffer functionality (to optimize IO).

`PrintWriter` prints formatted text, you can provide format string along with the data to be printed, though it can directly work with any `Writer/OutputStream`, just to provide buffering, `Writer/OutputStream` is 1st passed to `BufferedWriter` then to have formatted text is passed to `PrintWriter`

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this kind of Writer chaining is about abstraction. [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) have some useful `print` and `println` methods that can be convenient if you want to print Strings and lines to a File. Working directly with [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), you would have to use a more "low level" API. And as you say `BufferedWriter` is about buffering. So it's basically a matter of what you want to output to the file, and what level of abstraction you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The objects are wrapped in this order because you want to use the outermost PrintWriter for its more sophisticated formatting.  BufferedWriter must be wrapped on something.  So FileWriter, as a result, is what BufferedWriter wraps and is the innermost object.