# How to use tables and .txt in Java?

Tags: java, text, data-manipulation

Im building a Car Rental program and what I want it to, for now, is:

- Register a user
- Register a car

using .txt files to store the data.

With the code I've written, I can register only a single car and user. Every time I run the register method for client or car, the last register is erased.

Can you help me with this? Also, later I'm going to implement a way to rent a car, but I don't know how to do that also, so if you have any ideas of how to do it, please tell me!

Also I intend to do it without SQL or such things.

This is the code I'm using to register a user (I'm using netbeans with JForm):

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String nomeClient = txtNomeClient.getText();
    String idClient = txtIdClient.getText();

    File file = new File("clients.txt");

    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        output.println(nomeClient);
        output.println(idClient);
        output.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client registed!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you **overwrite** the existing file `clients.txt`, instead of **appending** to it by calling `new PrintWriter(file)`. You can use the following code:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fileWriter));
```

This way, you append the end of the file, see the constructor [`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)). The documentation describes it perfectly:

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

The `FileWriter` is just used to open a file in append mode, as `PrintWriter` does not have a suitable constructor to do that directly. You could also write characters with it, but a `PrintWriter` allows for formatted output. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) of `FileWriter`:

> Convenience class for writing character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable.

The `PrintWriter` uses the `FileWriter` passed in its constructor to append to the destination file, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803350/filewrite-bufferedwriter-and-printwriter-combined) for a good explanation. As stated there, you could also use an `FileOutputStream`. There are multiple ways to do this.

Here is an example using a `FileOutputStream` and a `BufferedWriter`, which supports buffering and can reduce unnecessary writes that penalize performance.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("clients.txt", true); 
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileOutputStream);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter);
```

Comment: I have added an example for `BufferedWriter`,